# Create box with an unicode-based icon on the left

Tags: html, css

I want to create a CSS class that, when applied to a `div` or a `p` element will place that text in a colored box with an icon based on a unicode character vertically centered to the left of the text.   This is to use to create "To Do", "Note", "Warning" type call outs.

For example I have this so far:

```
.todo {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  float: right;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.todo:before {
  content: "\2714";
  font-size: 250%;
}
```

The usage of this class:

```
<div class="todo">
This is something that really needs to be done.   
Even if you don't want to still do it.
</div>
```

Gives me a result like:

[image: My To-Do Note]

What I would like to do is make the check-mark bigger (my `font-size` term seems to be ignored) and place it vertically centered in the box and to the left of all text.   Can this be done without requiring styling or
other elements in the `div` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you started right with `:before` but use `position` to define its position and alignment.

```css
.tick{
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.tick::before {
    content: '\2713';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<p class="tick">To do</p>
```

Comment: You set me on the right path with this thanks.  I did have to modify the padding to make it look right however, and you want a left attribute bigger than zero otherwise the glyph bumps up against the left edge.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    ul {
      background-color: lightyellow;
      float: left;
      border: solid black 1px;
      padding: 10px;
      max-width: 30%;
    }
    
    ul li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    ul .icon {
      float: left;
      font-size: 22px;
      padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <i class="fa fa-check icon"></i>
      <p>This is something that really needs to be done. Even if you don't want to still do it. This is something that really needs to be done. Even if you don't want to still do it.</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solution will be useful for another project I have.  For the current one I was trying to avoid imports and the marked answer is a bit simpler.